# AWS Elastic Transcoder: Rotate video

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm trying to rotate a video in a job that is created using the php SDK, i see the job get created with rotate to 90 but the output does not seem to be rotated from the original position, am i missing something or does the rotate not actually work?

I posted on the aws forums with no responses
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=226254

```
$job = $client->createJob(array(
    'PipelineId' => 'MYPIPELINE',
    'Input' => array(
        'Key' => 'MYVIDEOKEY',
        'FrameRate' => 'auto',
        'Resolution' => 'auto',
        'AspectRatio' => 'auto',
        'Interlaced' => 'auto',
        'Container' => 'auto',
    ),
    'OutputKeyPrefix' => 'MYPREFIX/',
    'Output' => array(
        'Key' => 'MYNEWKEYNAME',
        'ThumbnailPattern' => 'thumb-{count}',
        'Rotate' => 90,
        'PresetId' => 'MYPRESET',
        'Watermarks' => [
            [
                'InputKey' => 'MYOVERLAY',
                'PresetWatermarkId' => 'BottomRight'
            ]
        ]
    )
));
```

Answer (score -1):

So i figured it out, i guess i should have tested a bit more before posting but the simple answer is the rotate doesn't start 0 degree with the top of the video being at the top it's actually the left is top and rotates 90 around that.

[image]